# How to utilize .GroupBy based on two parameters?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a data which I need to split based on two fields. I am using `.GroupBy` to do that but looks like I am not getting desired result.

Here is my condition to split the data:

1. Split them by `supplierName`. (This can be simply done by `.GroupBy`. 2nd point is little tricky for me)
2. If the set of records from 1st contains same `partTypeCode` then split them as separate record.

For an example, following is the set of data I have where I have 3 records from `autozone` and one from `orielly`. I want data mentioned in `Desired Outcome`.

**My approaches:**

1. This is giving me first point result but grouping data by `OIL_FILTER` which is not what I want.

```
 var groupedList = items.GroupBy(x => x.supplierName)
                   .Select(g => new {
                       Key = g.Key,
                       Count = g.Count(),
                       itemGroup = g.GroupBy(x => x.partTypeCode)
                   }).ToList();
```

2. This also clubs N records with `partTypeCode` (which looks obvious from my 2nd filter)

```
  var groupedList = items.GroupBy(x => new { x.supplierName, x.partTypeCode }).ToList();
```

**Questions:**

- Is `.GroupBy` correct way to achieve what I want?
- If no, what is the ideal way to achieve my desired result?

**Data:**

```
[
    {
        "cartItemId": "7de1881e-41b3-493f-a342-c8e7c7d6c6ff",
        "partTypeCode": "OIL_FILTER",
        "quantity": 1,
        "manufacturerCode": "CHL",
        "supplierName": "autozone"
    },
    {
        "cartItemId": "111881e-41b3-493f-a342-c8e7c7d6c6ff",
        "partTypeCode": "VEHICLE_BATTERY",
        "quantity": 1,
        "manufacturerCode": "CHL",
        "supplierName": "autozone"
    },
    {
        "cartItemId": "222881e-41b3-493f-a342-c8e7c7d6c6ff",
        "partTypeCode": "F_DS_WIPER_BLADE",
        "quantity": 1,
        "manufacturerCode": "CHL",
        "supplierName": "orielly"
    },
    {
        "cartItemId": "3331881e-41b3-493f-a342-c8e7c7d6c6ff",
        "partTypeCode": "OIL_FILTER",
        "quantity": 1,
        "manufacturerCode": "CHL",
        "supplierName": "autozone"
    }
]
```

**Desired Outcome:**

```
1st collection
[
    {
        "cartItemId": "7de1881e-41b3-493f-a342-c8e7c7d6c6ff",
        "partTypeCode": "OIL_FILTER",
        "quantity": 1,
        "manufacturerCode": "CHL",
        "supplierName": "autozone"
    },
    {
        "cartItemId": "111881e-41b3-493f-a342-c8e7c7d6c6ff",
        "partTypeCode": "VEHICLE_BATTERY",
        "quantity": 1,
        "manufacturerCode": "CHL",
        "supplierName": "autozone"
    }
]

2nd collection
[
    {
        "cartItemId": "222881e-41b3-493f-a342-c8e7c7d6c6ff",
        "partTypeCode": "F_DS_WIPER_BLADE",
        "quantity": 1,
        "manufacturerCode": "CHL",
        "supplierName": "orielly"
    }
]

3rd collection
[
    {
        "cartItemId": "3331881e-41b3-493f-a342-c8e7c7d6c6ff",
        "partTypeCode": "OIL_FILTER",
        "quantity": 1,
        "manufacturerCode": "CHL",
        "supplierName": "autozone"
    }
]
```

Comment: It might be easier to first do the second point. Find all the data that has duplicate `partyTypeCode` and `supplierName`, take out the duplicates and store them in a separate list. Now you can simply group the rest of the data without duplicates and concat the separate lists at the end of everything. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: You say you want to split items than you say you want to use `GroupBy` - which is it? Are you splitting or grouping?

Comment: it sounds like you need to group first by supplierName and partyTypeCode, assign sequence numbers within each group, and then partially flatten out the results and regroup by supplierName and sequence number.

Comment: Would subsequent collections with matching `supplierName`s only contain duplicate items? Does order matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you need to group first by supplierName and partTypeCode, assign sequence numbers within each group, then partially flatten out the results, and regroup by supplierName and sequence number.

Something like the following might work:

```
var groupedList = items
    .GroupBy(item => new { item.supplierName, item.partTypeCode })
    .SelectMany(grp => grp.Select((item, index) => new { item, index } ))
    .GroupBy(
        ix => new { ix.item.supplierName, ix.index }, // New grouping
        ix => ix.item // item selector
    )
    .ToList();
```

How it works:

1. First, your collection is grouped by `supplierName` and `partTypeCode`. If any of these groups contain more than one item, we will want to split them out into separate groups in the final result.
2. (Ignore the `.SelectMany()` for the moment.) Inside it however, we take the items in each group and create a new combined object containing both the item and the index within the group. We use an overloaded form of `.Select()` that provides both the item and a sequence number to the lambda function. The first (and possibly only) item in each group is paired with `index = 0`. Any additional items will be paired with `index` values `1, 2, 3,` etc.
3. The containing `.SelectMany()` will now flatten out these collections into a single stream of item/index pairs.
4. Next, we apply another `.GroupBy()`, but this time we will group by `supplierName` and `index`, For each `supplierName`, if we only had items with distinct `partTypeCode` values, all of the index values will be 0, and all will be gathered in a single group. If there were multiples, each distinct index value (per `supplierName`) will yield a separate group. The second parameter to this overload of `.GroupBy()` is the item selector, which we use to drill down through the item/index pair to pull out the original item.
5. Finally a `.ToList()` pulls it all together into the final result.

If you care about which items go into which group, you can add an `.OrderBy()` before the `.Select()` in step 2.

You can also apply ordering to the final groups before the `.ToList()`. Perhaps `.OrderBy(grp => grp.Key.supplierName)` and `.ThenBy(grp => grp.Key.index)` or the reverse.

If you want a list of lists instead of a list of groupings, you can insert `.Select(grp => grp.ToList())` or  `.Select(grp => grp.OrderBy(...).ToList())` before the final `.ToList()`.

The full statement with all bells and whistles would be:

```
var groupedList = items
    .GroupBy(item => new { item.supplierName, item.partTypeCode })
    .SelectMany(grp => grp
        .OrderByDescending(item => item.quantity)
        .Select((item, index) => new { item, index })
    )
    .GroupBy(
        ix => new { ix.item.supplierName, ix.index }, // New grouping
        ix => ix.item // item selector
    )
    .OrderBy(grp => grp.Key.supplierName)
    .ThenBy(grp => grp.Key.index)
    .Select(grp => grp.OrderBy(item => item.partTypeCode).ToList())
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

This feels like a problem best solved by a custom LINQ extension method, but here is an answer using stock LINQ:

```
var ans = items.GroupBy(item => item.supplierName) // group by supplierName
               .Select(item_sg => item_sg.GroupBy(item => item.partTypeCode) // for each supplierName, group by partTypeCode
                                         .Select(item_pg => new { // return new object
                                                     items = item_pg.ToList(), // preserve original items
                                                     Count = item_pg.Count() // count of duplicate partTypeCodes
                                                 }))
               .SelectMany(icg => Enumerable.Range(1, icg.Max(ic => ic.Count)) // 1 .. max # of dups
                                            .Select(gnum => icg.Where(ic => ic.Count >= gnum) // filter to partTypeCodes for gnum'th group
                                                               .Select(ic => ic.items[gnum-1]) // back to original data
                                                               .ToList()));
```

Instead I would suggest a custom extension method - this one uses nested `Dictionary` objects to split the groups by the keys and move duplicate cart items to the next group. Because of this, it does not preserve the original order.

```
public static class IEnumerableExt {
    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> GroupWithNoDups<T, TGroupKey, TDupKey>(this IEnumerable<T> src, Func<T, TGroupKey> groupKeyFn, Func<T, TDupKey> dupKeyFn) {
        var ansGroupsMap = new Dictionary<TGroupKey, List<Dictionary<TDupKey, T>>>();
        foreach (var cartItem in src) {
            if (!ansGroupsMap.TryGetValue(groupKeyFn(cartItem), out var ansGroups)) {
                ansGroups = new List<Dictionary<TDupKey, T>>();
                ansGroupsMap[groupKeyFn(cartItem)] = ansGroups;
            }
            var addedToGroup = false;
            foreach (var ansGroup in ansGroups) {
                if (!ansGroup.ContainsKey(dupKeyFn(cartItem))) {
                    ansGroup[dupKeyFn(cartItem)] = cartItem;
                    addedToGroup = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!addedToGroup) {
                var newAnsGroup = new Dictionary<TDupKey, T>();
                newAnsGroup[dupKeyFn(cartItem)] = cartItem;
                ansGroups.Add(newAnsGroup);
            }
        }
        foreach (var ansGroups in ansGroupsMap.Values)
            foreach (var ansGroup in ansGroups)
                yield return ansGroup.Values;
    }
}
```

You would use it like this:

```
var ans = items.GroupWithNoDups(i => i.supplierName, i => i.partyTypeCode);
```